# Backup Firebird no C#?

Tags: c#, firebird, backup

Estou realizando um backup de um banco de dados Firebird no C# porém esta retornando o seguinte erro:

> **unrecognized service parameter block**

Segue abaixo meu código

```
string cmBackup = @"C:\Controle Escolar\Ano_2011\Banco de Dados\Backup\BACKUP_" + agora.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy") + ".GBK";

string cmBanco = @"C:\ProjetoLeMarc\LermarcSistemas\LermarcSistemas\bin\Debug\SISTEMABD.FDB";
string conexao = @"ServerType=1;User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Port=3050;Dialect=3;DataSorce=localhost;Database=C://Banco;"

FbBackup backupSvc = new FbBackup();
backupSvc.ConnectionString = conexao;
backupSvc.BackupFiles.Add(new FbBackupFile(cmBackup, 4096));
backupSvc.Verbose = true;
backupSvc.Options = FbBackupFlags.IgnoreLimbo;
backupSvc.Options = FbBackupFlags.NonTransportable;
backupSvc.ServiceOutput += (sender1, e1) => Console.WriteLine(e1.Message);
backupSvc.Execute();
```

Comment: Em qual linha dá o erro?

Comment: O erro se da na hora do .Execute();